# replacing newline sed

Tags: sed, replace

How to replace **\n** from a line using **sed** command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's gross, because sed normally processes a line at a time:

```
sed -e :a -e N -e 's/\n/ /' -e ta input.txt
```

This is nicer:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt
```

I chose to replace the newline with a space.  tr can only replace by a single character (or delete with the -d option).

Flexible and simple:

```
perl -ne 'chomp;print $_," "' input.txt
```

Where " " is whatever you want in place of the newline.

Comment: `tr` only works with one-character strings though, which the OP didn't specify.