# Sed: replacing newlines with "-z"?

Tags: sed

Problem: replace some regex with `\n` with `sed`.

Solution: there are many similar answers [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)][[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23850789/match-a-string-that-contains-a-newline-using-sed)][[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442702/replacing-newline-sed)][[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844650/sed-replacing-with-possible-newline)], and many other links that I won't link. All of them suggest you to create a new label `:a`, merge lines `N`, branch to `:a` if not end-of-file `$!ba`, and then do some command.

**That said...**
In the GNU sed manual, there is the `-z` option:

```
-z
--null-data
--zero-terminated

Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
(the ASCII ‘NUL’ character) instead of a newline. This option can
be used with commands like ‘sort -z’ and ‘find -print0’ to process
arbitrary file names.
```

So, first, for comparison reasons, if we try the naive approach:

```
$ seq 3 | sed 's/\n/ /g'
1
2
3
```

However, using this `-z` option:

```
$ seq 3 | sed -z 's/\n/ /g'
1 2 3
```

### The Real Question: Why?

Given that it "merges" all the lines, as specified in the documentation, I expected that I would have to use `\0` instead of `\n`, since:

> Treat the input as a set of lines, each terminated by a zero byte
>   (the ASCII ‘NUL’ character)

Since I didn't find any post related to it, I think I might be misunderstanding something here... So, what does it really do? Why does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `-z` changes what sed considers to be a line. `\n` remains `\n`, but it doesn't end a line, but the null character (which is represented as `\x0` in Sed) would. As there are no null bytes in the output of `seq`, the whole output is considered one line and processed in single iteration (i.e. replacing all `\n`'s by spaces).

Comment: I didn't quite understand your answer regarding the `NUL` character. It doesn't specify that the input must have this character. What I understand from that is that it will put a `\0` character in the end of each string, while treating every line as on thing. So, is the documentation wrong, or just my understanding?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. `sort -z` and `find -print0` add the `\0` character, `sed -z` just treats `\0` as the end-of-line marker instead of the default `\n`.

Comment: @yZaph Sed just sees a byte stream, and by default, the `\n` byte is considered to mark the end of a line. With `-z`, sed looks for `\0` bytes to denote line ends instead, and `\n` is treated like any other character. I think you assume that it will takes newline delimited strings and replace the `\n` with `\0`, but that's not the case.

Comment: Oh. I see. I understand it now. Thank you, guys.

Comment: Coming to understand this `-z` option in sed. This is a good explanation