# How can I express this regex with sed?

Tags: regex, macos, sed, freebsd

I have this regex that I would like to use with sed. I would like to use sed, since I want to batch process a few thousand files and my editor does not like that

Find: `"some_string":"ab[\s\S\n]+"other_string_`

Replace: `"some_string":"removed text"other_string_`

Find basically matches everything between some_string and other_string, including special chars like , ; - or _ and replaces it with a warning that text was removed.

I was thinking about combining the character classes `[[:space:]]` and `[[:alnum:]]`, which did not work.

Comment: See [Sed: replacing newlines with “-z”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538158/sed-replacing-newlines-with-z)

Comment: I get an error saying that z is an illegal option. Does this not work on Mac?

Comment: So, you have a FreeBSD sed, try `sed -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e 's/"some_string":"ab.*"other_string_/"some_string":"removed text"other_string_/g' file`. Is there any more text on the *same line* after `other_string_`?

Comment: Nice. How can I do that in place?

Comment: Try: `perl -i -0777 's/(?s)("some_string":)"ab.+"(other_string_)/$1"removed text"$2/g' file`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works with `sed -e -I '' ...` Could you post an answer so I can give you an upvote for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MacOS FreeBSD `sed`, you can use

```sh
sed -i '' -e '1h;2,$H;$!d;g' -e 's/"some_string":"ab.*"other_string_/"some_string":"removed text"other_string_/g' file
```

The `1h;2,$H;$!d;g` part reads the whole file into memory so that all line breaks are exposed to the regex, and then `"some_string":"ab.*"other_string_` matches text from `"some_string":"ab` till the last occurrence of `"other_string_` and replaces with the RHS text.

You need to use `-i ''` with FreeBSD `sed` to enforce inline file modification.

By the way, if you decide to use `perl`, you really can use the `-0777` option to enable file slurping with the `s` modifier (that makes `.` match any chars including line break chars) and use something like

```sh
perl -i -0777 's/"some_string":"\Kab.*(?="other_string_)/removed text/gs' file
```

Here,

- `"some_string":"` - matches literal text
- `\K` - omits the text matched so far from the current match memory buffer
- `ab` - matches `ab`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as many as possible
- **OR** `.*?`  - any zero or more chars as **few** as possible
- `(?="other_string_)` - a positive lookahead (that matches the text but does not append to the match value) making sure there is `"other_string_` immediately on the right.